# Facebook open graphs resetting

Tags: php, jquery

What I want to do is to reset the metadata in a web page dynamically and I'm thinking like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php if(isset($title)){echo $title;} ?>" />
```

I want to set the variable $title as I hover over a button on the page. I know I can capture that with jquery so what I need to do is to pass the data to a php script. As jquery is client side and php is server side, I can't see how to achieve it. Although the following code is nonsense, I hope it will help explain the sort of thing I want to achieve:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('button selector').hover(function(){
        var mdata = 'Some value';
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
    if(isset(mdata)){
        $phpvariable = mdata;
    }
?>
```

Is there some way of achieving that effect? Maybe I could do it all with jquery?

Comment: Are you trying to *permanently* change the meta property for *all* users, or are you trying to *temporarily* change it for just the current user?

Comment: I was trying to change the og tags for facebook like buttons so I could have different tags related to different like buttons (on the same page). I've subsequently been steered towards a solution involving a separate page related to each like button that contains the customized og tags for that button. Seems to work.